# Copying keyframes makes objects snap to one point

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am quite new to blender, and I wanted to make two fractured rigid body balls collide in the air, but I am running into problems. I can make a single pice of the fracture move, and then become dynamic which is what I want, but when I try to copy the animation data to all of the other pices, it copies the location keyframes too resulting in all the fractured pices teleporting to a single point(Not what I want). Is there a way to copy the animation data so that the whole ball moves as a single part, and then shatters when it collides with the other ball?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to prevent fractured pieces from going into a single point, move all the fracture origins to the center of the ball. You can do this by selecting all the fractures, Shift+S, Cursor to selected, Ctrl+Atl+Shift+C, Origin to 3D cursor. And then copy the animation data to other pieces or do what I did in the below file.

Please check the layer2 in attached files to see how I implemented the collision.
[image]

I parented the fractures to empties and animated the empties.

For all the fractures just until a few frames before the collision (at about 70 frame), I kept rigid body 'dynamic' option off and 'Animated' on. After this point, 'Animated' off and 'dynamic' on. Let me know if you need more clarification.

[image]